# PHP while on IOS Safari

Tags: php, google-chrome, safari

This code works on android chrome but it is not work on IOS safari. Why?

```
ob_end_flush();
while(true){
echo rand(1,100);
flush();
sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: Please share how the code is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> flush() may not be able to override the buffering scheme of your web server and it has no effect on any client-side buffering in the browser. It also doesn't affect PHP's userspace output buffering mechanism. **This means you will have to call both ob_flush() and flush() to flush the ob output buffers if you are using those.**

**[Reference](http://php.net/flush)**

That means you have to use

```
ob_flush();
flush();
```

Comment: while(true){
echo rand(1,100);
ob_flush();
flush();
sleep(1);
}
This php code not work on ios safari yet.